# Azure IoT Hub, connecting two devices and make them communicate

Tags: raspberry-pi, communication, iot, azure-iot-hub, philips-hue

i am new to IoT and Azure but at the moment i want to connect a raspberry pi and the philips hue bulb to the IoT Hub. I already did this and i can communicate between the raspberry pi and the IoT Hub. I can send messages and store them in a Storage container.
But the biggest problem for me is to make the two devices communicate. My goal is that i send a message from the pi to the hub with a certain word, for example 'blue' and then the bulb changes its colour to blue. What is the best way to this? I really dont know how to proceed.

Help and advice would really be appreciated.

Greetings, Julian

Comment: thats not true. I searched for a lot of tutorials and tried out the logic app and some other things but i just cant get it working because it is such a new field for me. I am obviously missing some important feature but i just dont find it.

Comment: have a look at the following link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/668f0752-fc86-4c66-bac5-e1603c99cff2/sending-d2c-messages-on-azure-iot-hub-via-android-using-android-studio?forum=azureiothub

Answer (score 0):

Device to device communication is not available, hence you have to use IoT Hub as the broken between the two devices.  There are a few ways to do this:

1. Use your Raspberry Pi as a controller by building a back-end application to control other devices.  You can find a tutorial on how to control other devices [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-control-device-node).  You'd need to connect the Phillips hue bulb to IoT Hub as well.
2. Use your Raspberry Pi as an event triggering end-device, and use our [integration features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-event-grid-routing-comparison) to route the command and then sends the command to Phillips hue bulb using Microsoft Flow.

Our reference architecture is documented [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-iot-reference-architecture-update/).